# How can I import my .py file into my Nodejs project?

Tags: python, mysql, node.js, pandas

My project is composed as follows;

```
.crud.js
--database
.db.js
--env
.env
--log
--node modules
--public
-css
-images
-js
--views
index.ejs
admuser.ejs
.gitignore
.app.js
.logger.js
.package-lock.json
.package.json
.router.js
```

[image]

The truth is that I am new in this whole world of programming. And I would like to know how I can introduce a .py file, with more or less this structure,

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#carga de datos
df = pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx',sheet_name="datos")


#df = df.sort_values(by="Indicador", ascending=False)

trace0 = go.Bar(x=df["Subcategoria"], y=df["Indicador"], name="Indicador", marker={"color":"#32EC14"})
trace1 = go.Bar(x=df["Subcategoria"], y=df["Valor Encontrado"], name="Valor Encontrado", marker={"color":"#EC1414"})
data = [trace0, trace1]

#data = [go.Bar(x=df["Subcategoria"], y=df["Indicador"])]


layout = go.Layout(title = "Subcategorias (Indicador vs Valor Encontrado)",
                    xaxis=dict(title="Subcategoria"),
                    yaxis=dict(title="Valores Alcanzados")
                    )

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

pyo.plot(fig, filename="Dashboard.html")
```

It is more or less being able to import a dashboard with plotly in my project but I am handling .js files.
I have been told possible solutions;

1. I could handle django but I'm already handling node js, so I don't know what clash that might cause.
2. If I could put the python code together to run with nodejs.
3. Export the dashboard to an html file

But what I want is that through another .ejs file, load an excel file and export that to the dashboard.

I hope you can understand

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you tried [tools like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-calls-python)?

Comment: You are using NodeJS which is a JavaScript technology and you want to integrate support for Python. It looks like you mostly just want to use Python for generating graphs. I highly recommend against attempting to execute Python from your NodeJS app. Instead you should either generate the graphs ahead of time and include them in your NodeJS project as assets, or convert the Python code into a NodeJS equivalent. Don't try mixing the languages unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using JSPyBridge js Packages.
Also look at this one https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34501928)